# Column manipulation in R

Tags: r

I am writing an R code to get some data out of a column. The columns look like this
[image]

So, I want a user to define a value and values below that number should be changed to a 1 and above that value to be changed to a zero. I wrote the code,

```
dist <- readline(prompt = "Enter the distance below which you are interested: ")
df_col1 <- ifelse (df_col <= dist, 0, 1)
```

However, this is not working as I want it to and the wrong columns are being assigned the value of 1. The user should also be able to enter decimal values. Thank you in advance.

**Also, df_col is a table with 5064 obs of 13 variables, however, df_col1 becomes a large matrix (65832 elements, 515.5 Kb). I do not want this to happen. How to I get df_col1 also to stay as a table with 5064 obs of 13 variables.**

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `readline()` with `as.numeric` like this:

```
as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter the distance below which you are interested: "))
```

Essentially, the data is read in as a character and you need it as a numeric to perform the appropriate comparison with `<=`.

If you'd like to keep the entire data.frame as-is, not just a single column, then I suggest using a `dplyr` approach like this:

```
dist <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter the distance below which you are interested: ")) 
f <- function(x, dist) if_else(x <= dist, 0, 1)
df_col %>%
  mutate_each(funs(f(.,dist)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Steven, there is also an edit to the question which follows on what I got from your answer.

Comment: You want to update every value in the `data.frame` according to that logic?

Comment: That would be ideal

Comment: Gives the error        no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Yes, you need to define your logic as a function use `mutate_each` because the operation needs to run on every column. See my edited answer.